# Will the dihedral angles of the Platonic solids become rational if one switches to radians?

Tags: geometry, rational-numbers, platonic-solids

It seems that it could be possible for the dihedral angles of the platonic solids to be rational if one were to stop using our biased degree units and use the units natural to the platonic realm:  radians.

Obviously, the cube is 1/4pi radians already and serves as one example, but will the other solids show up with rational multiples of pi?

Also, to support my cause, there is a rule for the angles of each vertex in a closed n-gon (pi*(1-(2/n))) for 2 dimensions -- which always gives rational factors for any number of sides.  There must be something similar for 3 dimensions, yes?  OR why would it jump from rational numbers in 2d to irrational numbers in 3d?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that by a rational angle in the unit of radians you still mean a rational multiple of $\pi$, as otherwise already the cube is a counterexample. If so, then the answer still is: unfortunately not.

Check out [this list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_polyhedron_dihedral_angles) of dihedral angles in platonic solids. The angle of the tetrahedron is $\arccos(1/3)$, i.e. the arcus cosine of a rational number.

By [Niven's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) this is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @Marco If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark left of it.

Comment: Not quite.  I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Marcos You questions was posted and answered many months ago. On Math.SE it is usually considered not acceptable to change or extend a question significantly after it has received an acceptable answer (which I would argue my answer is), especially after this much time. The expected behavior is to accept the answer to your original question, even if it does no longer reflect your intend perfectly, and then post a new and more precise question. The value in the older question/answer would then be that you learned what better question you actually wanted to ask.

Comment: You said the cube is a "counterexample".  The cube is an example, rather, of my point.  My claim is that all closed, "regular", polyhedra will have similar rational relationships, much like their two-dimensional counterparts, but I don't know how to prove (or disprove) this.

Comment: Further, the list on wikipedia for dihedral angles relies on obscurantism -- arcosines for a closed, regular polyhedron?  No.  This is bullshit math without clear proof.  Is the cube just magically rational and all other regular solids irrational?  And two dimensions rational while three is irrational?  That doesn't make sense and I haven't seen a sufficient proof or explanation.

Comment: @Marcos I do not claim that the cube is a counterexample if you meant rational *multiples of $\pi$*, which it seems you did. The value given on Wikipedia for the tetrahedron angle is accurate. If you have doubts, try to compute it, search for a proof, or ask a question about it on Math.SE. Your original question asked about "whether it is the case", which I disconfirmed. Your modified question asks "why is it not the case", which no reasonable modification of my answer will suffice to address. Your chances to receive a satisfying answer are much higher if you ask a new question.